# Wordpress Shortcode not passing variable from function (Newbie)

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

Here is the snippet of code in question:

```
function hoursearned_func($user) {
    $key = 'Service Hours Earned';
    if(isset($user[$key])) {
        $result = $user[$key];
    }
return "Service Hours Earned: ".$result." Hours";
}
add_shortcode('hoursearned', 'hoursearned_func');
```

This small function simply returns the value of an array given the key, but when calling the shortcode, [hoursearned], it only displays:

```
Service Hours Earned: Hours
```

rather than:

```
Service Hours Earned: 200 Hours
```

Where 200 is a string that is returned by the function hoursearned_func given $user.

For some reason Wordpress is not passing the returned variables from the functions to the shortcodes.  How can I get Wordpress to show the result from the function?

Here is the full code if that helps... (note that all of this is being loaded as a plugin)

```
//Dump CSV file (SalesForce Report) to php array to be parsed..
add_action('dump_csv_array', 'dump_csv_array', 10);
function dump_csv_array(){
    $data = array();
    $header = NULL;
    if (($file = fopen('http://blah.com/info.csv', 'r')) !==FALSE) { //The link to the CSV is insignificant
        while (($row = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ",")) !==FALSE) {
            if(!$header)
                $header = $row;
            else
                $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
            }
    fclose($file);
    }
    return $data;
}

$multiarray = (array) dump_csv_array();
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
$user_email = $current_user->user_email;

//Parses the multidimensional array of Dumped CSV info. Looks up the current user's email and returns a single array of the current user's SalesForce information.  
function parse_array($multiarray, $user_email){
    $array = (array) $multiarray;
    $email = $user_email;       
        if(is_user_logged_in() === true ) {
            foreach($array as $subarray) {
                if(isset($subarray['Email']) && $subarray['Email'] == $email) {
                    $data = $subarray;
                }   
            }
        }
        else {
            return NULL;
        }
return $data;
}

$user = parse_array($multiarray, $user_email);

//Defines Shortcodes and their Functions
function hoursearned_func($user) {
    $key = 'Service Hours Earned';
    if(isset($user[$key])) {
        $result = $user[$key];
    }
return "Service Hours Earned: ".$result." Hours";
}


function hoursawarded_func($user) {
$key = 'Service Hours Awarded';
    if(isset($user[$key])) {
        $result = $user[$key];
    }
return "Service Hours Awarded: ".$result." Hours";
}

function rank_func($user) {
$key = 'Rank';
    if(isset($user[$key])) {
        $result = $user[$key];
    }
return "Rank: ".$result;
}

function memstatus_func($user) {
    $key = 'Membership Status';
    if(isset($user[$key])) {
        $result = $user[$key];
    }
return "Status: ".$result;
}

function register($atts) {
    add_shortcode( 'hoursearned', 'hoursearned_func');
    add_shortcode( 'hoursawarded', 'servicehours_func');
    add_shortcode( 'rank', 'rank_func');
    add_shortcode( 'memstatus', 'memstatus_func');
}
add_action('init', 'register');
var_dump(hoursearned_func($user));
```

Comment: It seems like your variable `$result` is not set. What is passed into `$user`, does it contain an array with the key 'Service Hours Earned'?

Comment: @Fleuv Yes, `$user` is an array. For example `var_dump($user)` would return: 
`array (size=10) 'First Name' => string 'John' (length=6) 'Last Name' => string 'Doe' (length=6) 'Email' => string 'spammanabc@website.com' (length=21) 'Phone' => string '(123) 456-7890' (length=14) 'Grad Year' => string '2000' (length=4) 'School' => string 'School' (length=7) 'Service Hours Earned' => string '200' (length=3) 'Service Hours Awarded' => string '10' (length=1) 'Rank' => string 'MasterChief' (length=7) 'Membership Status' => string 'Active Member' (length=13)`

Comment: @Fleuv I am also unsure about $result not being set (sorry I am extremely new to php).  Shouldn't $result be set since I have already declared it within the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create a shortcode with attributes, (or) retrieve the `$user` data inside the shortcode's function and set them as default values.

```
function example_func($atts) {
    $user = get_user_array(); //Retrieve the data
    $atts = shortcode_atts($user, $atts);
    return 'example: ' . $atts['foo'] . ' ' . $atts['bar'];
}
add_shortcode('example', 'example_func');
```

Have a look at the [Shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) it basically explains everything.

Comment: Thanks very much! By calling `$user` within the shortcode function using `global $user` the shortcode can pass the variable that is returned.